# Print string based on screen width in PHP using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to print a string based on screen width in PHP using Javascript. If screen size is less than or equal to 400 then, echo will print "Mobile". If it is not then it will print "Desktop". But it is always printing Desktop. I also want to echo the value of screen width to ensure that it is measuring correctly.

This is my code.

```
<?php

$screenWidth = '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(screen.availWidth);</script>';

 echo $screenWidth; //I want to echo the value. But it is not coming.

 if ($screenWidth <= "400")

echo 'Mobile';

else 

echo 'Desktop';


?>
```

Comment: It isn't "coming" because Javascript isn't executed until the page is loaded on the client. Thus you need a Javascript only solution.

Comment: I am loading the page in my browser. What should be the correct code ?

Comment: You can check the screen width using Javascript, then redirect to the appropriate PHP page.

Comment: Atleast, I want to get the value of screenWidth

Comment: This is a possible solution: http://pastebin.com/udwncpAN